# How to avoid the mass in my controls that i added to the layout?

Tags: android

I using the 'LinearLayout' and i add 4 controls.

```
       1. textView_1   - that contain the title of the application
       2. textView_2   - that contain some dynamic text
       3. Button       - that contain the title of the application
       4. ImageView    - that contain the application logo ( image )
```

My Questions are

How can i keep the relation between all of those controls ? 
I want to make the first control to be 10% of the screen, the second to be 60%, the third to be 20% and the last to be 10%.

I also want to keep the font of the textview to be dynamic - so if the application will run on big screen ( tablet ) then the font will be grow according to the screen size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use layout_weight for distributing the space.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
>
   <TextView
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.1"
   />
   <TextView
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.6"
   />
   <Button
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.2"
   />
   <ImageView
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.1"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

try using "sp" to scale font size.

Comment: Thanks , what about the dynamic font size ?

Comment: sry, i don't know about that, would have mentioned earlier, if i knew.

Comment: you can give it a try with "sp", it is similar to "dp" , your font size will scale i think, i din't try this, but you can always give it a try. lemme know if this works,so that i can include in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LinearLayout`s weight attributes to archieve the space distribution.
Just give the outer linearlayout a `android:weightSum=1.0` and set height and width to `fill_parent`. Then give each child view a `android:layout_height` attribute with the value `0dp` and a `android:layout_weight` attribute with a value below 0. The values can be used as percentages, since the total weight sum is 1.0, 1.0 equals 100%. When you give a child `android:layout_weight=0.1`, it will take 10% of the height.

But I'm not sure if there is a possibility for the auto-adjusting text size. You may have to write your own, custom view for that.

Answer (score 1):

using the android:layout_weight tag, you can specify percentages. In the bellow example the two buttons take respectively 40% and 60% of the available space.

```
    <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <Button
        android:text="left" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".60" /> 

    <Button
        android:text="right" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight=".40" />

</LinearLayout>
```